# Request read-only access to a user's github profile?

Tags: github, omniauth

I let users log in via Github with the `omniauth-github` gem.

However, the most basic scope that provides email address is `user`, which also includes write access to their profile (which I don't need, and is dissuading users).

How can I request read-only access to their profile?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but my team has been having the same issues so I post an answer for posterity.

The Omniauth-GitHub gem has [scopes](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) that allow you to ask for different sets of permissions. In your case, you want to leave scope blank, because this means

> public read-only access (includes public user profile info, public repo info, and gists).